# Is there any way to view which applications are accessing the Internet on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, networking, terminal, tracking

I think I remember a command line utility that did this, but I can't remember what it's called and a few Google searches turn up nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"
```

from [List open ports on your machine (Mac OS X)](http://juretta.com/log/2007/08/08/list_open_ports_on_your_machine_mac_os_x_/).

It was the second google result for "list sockets mac osx"

You could `grep` tcp or udp instead to get outbound ports instead of listening ports.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is to use [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html), but it's not free (although there is a trial version).